# ASP WebSite - how to get build time errors

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web

Having recently started doing more web development I've come across both:

- Web Applications
- Web Sites

From my understanding a Web application all gets compiled into the binaries and run. While a Web site essentially lazy compiles pages upon requests. Working with websites seems a lot nicer especially when dealing with a massive project (in my case Kentico CMS) because you don't need to worry about long build times and IIS recycles.

However what I don't understand is how you effectively protect against errors early on? It feels like the mode has switched from build errors, to runtime errors. So if I refactor a method signature by adding a new parameter for example how do I effectively ensure that I've not broken any calls (without using a Find all references / using external tooling)?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at test driven development if you are wanting to be sure that you are keeping errors out of your project.

If you do a web application yes it gets compiled and that is actually a bit faster even though load times can be longer. A web site is compiled as called and can be a bit slower. There is no reason you can't combine the two like I do.

Usually I do the presentation layer as a web site and then all the logic and data is all contained in dlls - gives a sort of the best of both worlds effect.  I can make small tweaks to my display pages without having to recompile (or if i have two users of the same application they can have totally different layouts) but the data layer and logic are all encapsulated and safe. Those pieces can be tested away from the site and if you really get ambitious then you could work in Continuous Integration to automatically deploy builds if they pass all the tests.

Lots of options.

Comment: Unfortunately the CMS we use doesn't lend itself well to TDD. Although it is something I'm looking at for the future.

Comment: What CMS - I have worked with a few of them and might have some ideas

Comment: This one in particular is Kentico